# An inline stl type list manager

Tags: c++, linked-list

Lets say I have an `std::vector<MyObject>`

Now from time to time I will need to add and remove some of these objects to and from a list. I could use a stl container list `std::list<MyObject*>` or even `std::vector<MyObject*>` for the list.

However this will require quite a lot of allocating and deallocating of memory if this lists change often.

What I normally do is define MyObject like:

```
class MyObject 
{
    stuff;
    MyObject* next;
};
```

And then hand link the objects into a linked list and unlink the objects as requires. This however does mean that I am hand coding a linked list whenever I want to do this which could be error prone.

What I would ideally like is something like:

```
class MyObject : public SomeListItem<MyObject> 
{
    stuff;
};
```

Where together with some management a `SomeList<MyObject>` class, the logic of my list is take care of. This should happen without any memory allocation since the linking pointers already exist in MyObject.

Does such a container exist in std or boost?

**Edit**
The problem is during the course of my algorithm, I constantly create and destroy numerous lists of pre-existing objects. Using a next pointer embedded into my objects means I can use these list with zero need to allocate memory.

std::list or slist require memory allocation and this creates an unacceptable overhead.

Comment: Using `std::vector<MyObject>` will not require a lot of allocating and deallocating of memory if the list changes often.

Comment: And to your question: [boost::intrusive::slist](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/intrusive.html) (for singly linked lists, like what you had before)

Comment: I don't understand why you're against using `std::list` but find it acceptable to hand-roll your own singly linked list. There's also `std::forward_list` in the standard library.

Comment: I am against std::list because I don't want to do memory allocation. The object are created at startup and destroyed later. The lists are just for some sort of intermediate processing. What I want is a standard list manager that does not do any memory allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for exactly [Boost Intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/intrusive.html), which offers linked lists and other containers.  It works pretty much exactly like you described--you can inherit from its base class and then link your objects together in a container.  Of course there's more to it than that, lots more features, it's Boost after all.

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I am interested in.